# unhandled exception: org.xml.sax.SAXException

Tags: java, android

I am reading an RSS newsfeed and want to check if the calling App has been cancelled/stopped (eg device rotated). Most RSS feeds have a loop in them which allows a statement in the loop to check for isCancelled(). I am using what is described as a Simplified SAX read. There is no loop. I call the parse, and have handlers for different items. I have one of them, (end Element) to check for isCancelled().
I get "unhandled exception: org.xml.sax.SAXException", on the red underlined throw statement. It will not compile.
I have tried as many combinations as I can think of where the try/catch statements go, and putting in the org.xml.sax.
I presume one option I have is to use one of teh RSS feed read options that has a loop, but if possible, I would like to use this simplified SAX read as it is supposed to be the most efficient.

```
public ArrayList<FeedItem> GetWithSimplifiedSax(String theUrl)
    throws SAXException { 
try {
    url= new URL(theUrl);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

    final FeedItem currentItem = new FeedItem(); 
    RootElement root = new RootElement("rss");
    final ArrayList<FeedItem> feedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    android.sax.Element channel = root.getChild("channel");
    android.sax.Element item = channel.getChild("item");

    item.setEndElementListener(new EndElementListener(){
        public void end() {
            feedItems.add(currentItem.myCopy());
            if(isCancelled()){ 
                throw new SAXException("cancel");
             //<<DOES NOT LIKE ABOVE LINE
             // *** Gives unhandled exception:org.xml.sax.SAXException
            }
        }
    });
    item.getChild("title").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
        public void end(String body) {
            currentItem.setTitle(body); 
        }
    });
    item.getChild("link").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
        public void end(String body) {
            currentItem.setLink(body);
        }
    });
    item.getChild("description").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
        public void end(String body) {
            currentItem.setDescription(body);
        }
    });
    item.getChild("pubdate").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
        public void end(String body) {
            currentItem.setPubDate(body);
        }
    });


    try {
        Xml.parse(inputStream, Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
    } catch(SAXException e){
        Log.e("SAX", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    return feedItems;
} catch ( IOException  e) {
    Log.e("MYERROR", e.getMessage());
    //e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
} //catch (org.xml.sax.SAXException e) {
  //  Log.e("SAX", e.getMessage());
   // //e.printStackTrace();
  //  return null;
//} //try catch
```

} //method: public ... simplified SAX

Comment: its obviously because `EndElementListener.end` doesn't have `throws` defined ...

Comment: ..and I presume that I have to do a SAXException as that will somehow stop the parser doing any more work

Comment: [then throw RuntimeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) and catch it from `Xml.parse`

Comment: I have tried placing throws SAXException with the function statement. What would be the solution? apart from using one of the other RSS feed readers?

Comment: I did what you said. It looks better. I had to put in

Comment: ...catch(RuntimeException | SAXException e) on the Xml.parse. But that seems to answer my problem. Do I mark this as answered? I dont see a button to say "ansered"

Comment: there is no such button ... you may answer to your question by yourself